# GIMP: How to crop a layer?

Tags: gimp, images, photo-editing

I have a screenshot where I want only a part of the pasted image, and I want to turn the white that's in it transparent.

First I need to crop the pasted image. I have selected the layer and a rectangle which I want. I can't seem to find the option that crops the current layer to the current selection. What's this called?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are *at least* two ways to crop your image.

**(1)** First select the region of the image you want to have, by using the...

[image: Rectangle Select Tool]

- **Rectangle Select Tool** (<kbd>R</kbd>) to make a rectangular selection
- **Ellipse Select Tool** (<kbd>E</kbd>) to make an elliptical selection
- **Free Select Tool** (<kbd>F</kbd>) to make a hand-drawn selection
- **Fuzzy Select Tool** (<kbd>U</kbd>) to make a color-based contiguous selection

*(All of these are next to each other at the top of the Toolbox.)*

...then go to **Image** menu > select **Crop to Selection** option.

---

**(2)** Another way of doing it is by using the **Crop Tool** (in the **Toolbox**) to make a selection, and double-clicking anywhere inside the selection (or hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>) to crop.

[image: Crop Tool]

***PS:*** And of course, I'm not Gimp expert, so do let me know if there are any other ways to do it.

Comment: Beautiful answer.

Comment: Tested as of gimp 2.10.18 OP there is a "Layer > Crop to Selection" which is likely what OP wants instead of "Image > Crop to Selection" in this case, mentioned at: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7137/gimp-how-to-crop-a-layer/113952#113952

Answer (score 17):

To crop a *layer*:

1. Double-click the "Crop Tool" in the Toolbox.

[image: Crop Tool icon in Toolbox]

2. In the Crop Tool's "Tool Options" dialog, check the checkbox next to "Current Layer Only".

[image: Crop Tool "Tool Options" dialog]
<sub>(source: [gimp.org](https://docs.gimp.org/en/images/toolbox/tool-options-crop.png))</sub>

Note: By selecting this box, all future use of the crop tool will only apply to the current layer.  You must open this dialog again and uncheck the checkbox to crop the image again.

Comment: Can't thank you enough! Coming from photoshop I had so much frustration with this.

Answer (score 4):

This method works in GIMP 2.8, it may work in other versions too:

1. Make the layer you want to crop the current layer.
2. Click the rectangle selection tool in the toolbox.
3. Select the area of the current layer that you want to keep.
4. In the "Layer" menu, select "Crop to Selection."

This crops the current layer, while leaving the crop tool in the toolbox alone, allowing you to easily use that to crop the entire image without having to remember to switch it back to "Crop Image."

Comment: Not very different from solution #1 in @its_me's answer...

Comment: Exactly, except answer #1 in @its_me's answer crops the entire image, not just the current layer.

Comment: +1 This is the method that worked for me compared to others. Other given answers crop the entire image not just the active layer.