# How to prevent edges of a layer without transparency from becoming semi-transparent when scaling up with Shift+S in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

If I open a JPG as a layer and scale it up 2x with the Shift+S tool, I notice that the edges of the scaled images are now semi-transparent, even though the JPG does not have transparency information of course.

How to prevent that?

Tested on GIMP 2.10.18.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution at: http://gimpchat.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=12815#p173563 by using:

- Layer
- Scale layer

instead of Shift + S. I then just use the default Cubic interpolation provided there.

Comment: Please note that the semi-transparency is due to the Scale Tool which (unlike Scale Layer) adds an alpha channel to the image. If you are more comfortable to use the Scale Tool (Shift + S), then you simply need to remove the alpha channel after the operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scale the image use `Image ➤ Scale image` (this scales everything in the image: layers, channels and path). You can also use `Layer ➤ Scale layer` to scale a specific layer to specific dimensions. The scale tool is more meant to adjust the layer size with regard to something else in the image. You get fuzzy edges if you move the top left corner of the layer when using the tool.

Interpolation type is irrelevant for the semi-transparency, it is usually best to use NoHalo.